# Convert Pandas Dataframe to email Attachment using MIMEApplication

Tags: python, pandas, email, aws-lambda, mime

I am using MIMEApplication to convert my dataframe to an attachment and I am seeing the following error when this happens. Below is my code for context:

```
att = MIMEApplication(dataframe)
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='+ 'test.csv')
```

This code is resulting in the following error:

```
TypeError: expected bytes-like object, not NoneType
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear [MIMEApplication](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.mime.html).  `data` parameter has to be a string.  Clearly a data frame is a binary object.  So choose your string representation....  CSV, HTML etc

```
import pandas as pd
import email.mime.application

sf = pd.DataFrame(columns=[tuple([f"label{i//2}",f"f{i+1}"]) for i in range(6)])
sf = sf.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(sf.columns), axis=1)

att = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(sf.to_csv())
att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='+ 'test.csv')
```